# Top Down EJB Web Service Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb, java2wsdl

I'm trying to create a Web Service Skeleton using the EJB but I don't see any options. How can get those options and create Top down EJB Web service using the Eclipse? I'm using Eclipse Neon.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to install app server, like a IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools from Eclipse Marketplace to create EJB WebService

This is beacuse Enterprise JavaBean is a component in a Java EE application server